# SqlBulkCopy: Error en ColumnName

Tags: sql-server, vb.net

Quiero implementar el uso de SqlBulkCopy para reducir los tiempos de insertado en una migración que estoy haciendo de un sistema.

En **`StrArray(x)`** obtengo el nombre las columnas tal cual están en la tabla donde quiero insertar la información, el cual las almaceno en un GridView, y en **`StrArray(w)`** el nombre de las columnas es exactamente el mismo que en el GridView, esto ya esta almacenado en el archivo .csv.

```
Dim directorio as String = "C:\Proyect\Carga.csv"
Dim sr As StreamReader = New StreamReader(directorio)
Dim line As String = sr.ReadLine()
Dim strArray As String() = line.Split(",")
Dim dt As DataTable = New DataTable()
Dim row As DataRow

   For Each s As String In strArray
        dt.Columns.Add(New DataColumn())
   Next

   Do
     row = dt.NewRow()
     row.ItemArray = line.Split(",")
     dt.Rows.Add(row)
     i = i + 1
     line = sr.ReadLine()
   Loop While Not line = String.Empty

   Dim bc As SqlBulkCopy = New SqlBulkCopy(conn, SqlBulkCopyOptions.KeepIdentity, Nothing)
   Dim x as string = 0

   For w = 1 to StrArray - 1
     bc.ColumnMappings.Add(strArray(w), strArray(x))
     x = x + 1
   Next

   bc.DestinationTableName = "dbo." & Nombre_Tabla & ""
   bc.WriteToServer(dt)
```

Pero, al intentar realizar el insert me arroja una excepción:

```
La ColumnName 'ID_Carga' no coincide con ninguna columna del origen de datos.
```

Ya que **`StrArray(w)`** y **`StrArray(x)`** tienen exactamente los mismos nombres en relación Archivo-Tabla al momento de utilizar **ColumnMappings.Add**, ¿por qué me da ese error y como puedo darle solución?

Estoy usando SQL Server 2008 R2 en un proyecto de VS2017.